Can't change query settings for recent posts in WordPress
Good afternoon!
For the last 24 hours I've been trying to change the settings of post output on the main page. I have added a "Posts/Image at left" pattern on the main page.
Let's say I need to receive only the last 2 posts. Then I have to make a change in the query. For this purpose I have written the following code in functions.php(in the beginning):
function be_change_event_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        var_dump("Hey");
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'be_change_event_posts_per_page' );

But it still outputs all three posts I have. Moreover var_dump("Hey"); works and outputs "Hey" at the top of the page, that is up to this point the code works.
I also can't change the sorting method (asc/desc). What can I do here?
thx:)

I just tried changing the theme to the default and it worked, it gave me exactly two posts.

Then the theme you are using is probably hooking into this itself already, and undoing your modifications at a later time. Have you tried to use a higher priority in your add_action call?

@CBroe yes, I've tried to use add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'be_change_event_posts_per_page', 20); (and higher values) but it doesn't work...

Perhaps your theme is not actually using the main query result for the output you are seeing, but makes its own query? (It should rather not, but sometime poorly written themes do.)

@CBroe But I'm not taking patterns from the theme, I'm taking patterns from the standard set. Or does it not matter?

@CBroe Should I just write my query from scratch? But how can I do it more correctly? Just through an html block in the editor?

@maxet24 can you try add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'be_change_event_posts_per_page', PHP_INT_MAX); to ensure there is no problem with the action priority?

@CBroe It doesn't work either. Now I loaded a standard theme and in it I put the "Posts/Image at left" pattern on the home page and it too shows 3 elements instead of two. If I don't change anything on the main page in this theme there is a section "Watch, Read, Listen", where 3 posts in the editor, but on the site itself it doesn't show posts at all. Magic...

@CBroe So I think it would be easier for me to write it myself from scratch. But how do you do it right?
